# Option to pin the top bar to see it when scrolling

Tags: feature-request

It would be very useful if we could (optionally) pin the top bar, so be able to see new notifications in the Recent Inbox Messages while scrolling a page.
For example, this

[image: Screenshot with vertical scroller in top position]

would become this other

[image: Screenshot with vertical scroller in middle position]

we could see that there is an incoming message (from that red square with an 1), even while scrolling the page.

Comment: The answer to the linked post includes info about a user script that does this.

Comment: Dupe on Meta.SE: [Should the top navigation be frozen?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101385)